# A good place to define your case classes?

Tags: scala

IS there a suggested best practise for where to define your case classes in Scala? 
For example, suppose you have a few actors sending messages to each other where should the case classes be defined?

In a shared package?  In one of the actors - if so which one?

Or in a package object, for example:

```
package object mypackage {
  case object Ping
  case object Pong
  case object Stop
}
```

if the actors are in the same package?

Just trying to figure out best practise here.

Comment: I would say package object is the best place for them (if all actors are in the same package).

Comment: I have to disagree. Package objects have a giant disadvantage: they must be compiled all at once (in other words, all in one file). Package objects have their use, but defining classes in package objects has no advantage over simply defining them in separate files (in said package).

Comment: Do you collate them in any special way to keep them separate to other package stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I Usually put the message case classes in with the actor's themselves, the downside is that you can't share message classes between actors in that way, but in practice that has never been a problem for me and it's a bit more verbose when calling them eq:

```
MyActor ! MyActor.MyMessage
```

Comment: Assles In the receiving Actor I suppose?  I guess anyone who is sending a message to that Actor will have a dependency to that actor anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I have not found a best practise for this issue, but I can tell you how I do it. For me it depends on the complexity of the messages. If I have highly branched messages with inheritance, I usually put them into an own package called "message". If I have only some messages used by many Actors in the same package, I define the messages in a package object. But if there are messages, that are only used by a single actor (for example if I want to emulate a private recursive function), I define these messages in the Actor using them. Sometimes a mix of all of this might be the best way to go on this.